# save image to database in php direct from a url

Tags: php

I have tried to download images to a directory but now I want to save the images to the database using BLOB type by not using the File Chooser. I mean save the images direct from a URL:

Say:

```
http://someserver.com/images/imageone.gif
```

How can I save that directly to database? Do I have to download it first before saving to database? Please help me..

Comment: I think they deserve even votes :)

Comment: as stated above, i tried downloading the images to a directory which actually works and also tried to insert image to database using the file chooser in which you select the images from your local machine and submit (insert to database, also worked) I wanted to save it automatically straight from a URL..is it possible?

Comment: @silent_coder14, you mentioned that you succed to insert image to DB using file chooser, how did you do that?. I'm trying to insert image base64 url(which is realy large) using text type but it's not working. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you would save any other data.

```
$imageContents = file_get_contents('http://someserver.com/images/imageone.gif');
$imageContentsEscaped = mysql_real_escape_string($imageContents, $link);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (imageData) VALUES ('$imageContentsEscaped')", $link);
```

Make sure the column you want to save the image data to is set to a binary type such as BLOB.

Answer (score 1):

```
// download image to memory
$image = file_get_contents('http://example.com/my/image.jpg');

// open PDO connection
$db = ...;

// insert downloaded data to the DB
$sql = 'insert into my_table(filename, content) values (?,?)';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, 'my/image.jpg');
$stmt->bindParam(2, $image, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->execute();
```